# Filament group responsive carousel doesn't work with twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, carousel

The http://filamentgroup.com/lab/responsive_carousel/ fits my needs better than the carousel that comes with twitter bootstrap, but they are incompatible (add bootstrap.js and the filament group carousel dies).

I thought about prepending the filament group class with fgcarousel but this could have maintenance issues down the road for upgrades.

Any thoughts on a quick way to have them play nice?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `bootstrap.js` with Bootstrap's [individual jQuery plugins](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/master/js) and only include the ones you need (optionally minifying/combining them into a single file). Just leave out carousel.